Word Numbered Paragraph Spacing
I am fighting with MS Word (Professional Plus 2016) to adjust the spacing between numbered 'paragraphs'
I have tried adjusting the "Space after paragraph" option in the "Paragraph" dialogue/options box - doing so adjusts the space at the end of the current list. This, to me, indicates that Word is not treating the numbered items as paragraphs (despite being created by hard return (enter button)).
I want to be able to to this without changing the line spacing (as doing so adjusts all lines - not just lines between numbered items).
Please see linked image for clarification. TIA.


MS Word uses list styles to set ¶ spacing. Set the list style. See https://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-custom-list-style-microsoft-word/

Use the Space Before and Space After paragraph formatting.
This should be a part of your style definition for styles associated with your numbering.
Note that fonts require certain minimum spacing to fully display properly.
Multi-level list numbering in Word has always been complex. See my answer to Advanced Numbering in Word.

And make sure "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" is unchecked
